# Adding an extra tick mark on the axes in a pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code plots a line on the Cartesian plane. I have three modifications that I would like to make.

```
  Extra tick marks at -10 and 10 on the x-axis, and 16 and 17 on the y-axis

  Extend the grid lines like horizontally and vertically something like "half a unit"

  Remove the white space surrounding the labels for the tick marks
```

Is there a convention about the graph of a function passing though a tick mark? In this case, the line is drawn over the "-3" tick mark on the x-axis.

```
\documentclass{amsart}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}




\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!50},major grid style={line width=.5pt,draw=gray!50},
    xmin=-11,xmax=11,
    ymin=-34/3,ymax=52/3,
    xtick={-9,-6,...,9},
    ytick={},
    grid=both,
    minor x tick num={2},
    minor y tick num={4},
    enlargelimits={abs=0},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny, fill=white},
    extra x ticks={-3, -6, -9},
    extra x tick labels={$\llap{$-$}3$, $\llap{$-$}6$, $\llap{$-$}9$},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex, shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel=\textit{x},ylabel=\textit{y},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south west}
]


\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, blue, domain=-10.5:10.5] {4/3*x + 3};
\addplot[samples=2, dashed, latex-latex, domain=-10.5:10.5] {7} node[pos=0.15, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize] {$y=7$};

\draw[fill] (3,7) circle (1.5pt);

\coordinate (A) at (-7,-19/3);
\coordinate (B) at (0,3);

\end{axis}


%A "pin" is drawn between the label for the graph and a point on the graph.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A) -- ($(A)!1.5cm!-90:(B)$);
\node[blue, anchor=north west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A)!1.5cm!-90:(B)$) {$y=\dfrac{4}{3} \, x + 3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You sort of already have the answer to the first one I suppose, with `extra x ticks` (and equivalently `extra y ticks`)? For the second one, you've explicitly extended the axis lines beyond the grid with the `shorten`s in the `axis line style`, so I suppose just modify the distance used there?  For the third one you have explicitly added the white fill with `fill=white` in the `ticklabel style`.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I do have the options `shorten >=-7.5pt` and `shorten <=-7.5pt` on the `axis line style`. I had supposed that these were only for the coordinate axes. How can I shorten the horizontal and vertical grid lines separately?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't really think quite clearly. I should rather have said that the grid lines extend from `xmin`/`ymin` to `xmax`/`ymin`, so modifying those changes the grid lines. (Because of the `shorten`s, the coordinate axes extend 7.5pt outside of those limits.)

Comment: To extend the grid, just make the whole plot larger and then shorten the axis more. To remove white background, try to look for "white" in your code.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I can avoid this limitation using a  `foreach` command. May you tell me how I can use it to draw these lines? For the vertical lines, I would use `line width=.1pt, draw=gray!25`, and I would have them drawn between -10.25 and 16.25. (I can use the code for these lines to draw the other grid lines.)

Comment: I clearly don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, because I don't see why you can't just set `ymin=-10.25,ymax=16.25`, but try e.g. `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-10,-8,...,10}{\draw [line width=.1pt, draw=gray!25] (#1,-10.25) -- (#1, 16.25);}`

Comment: Is it needed extra tick marks with or without labels ?